# Why is this not accessing the vector position?

Tags: c++, vector, void-pointers

I am writing a backtracking problem for my class and I have to implement some existing functions. This is one of the functions I have to implement. The `void *input` is where we are supposed to pass in the data, which in my case is a two-dimensional vector.

```
void process_solution(int a[], int k, void *input, bool *finished)
{
    int sumweight = 0;
    int sumvalue = 0;
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > *datavector = static_cast<std::vector<std::vector<int> >* >(input);
    for(unsigned i=0; i<sizeof(a); i++)
    {
        sumweight += a[i]*datavector[i][0];
        sumvalue += a[i]*datavector[i][1];
    }
}
```

However, I believe something is wrong with my cast, because I get an error at the line `sumweight += a[i]*datavector[i][0];`

> error: no match for 'operator*' in '*(a + ((long long unsigned int)(((long long unsigned int)i) * 4ull))) * (datavector + ((long long unsigned int)(((long long unsigned int)i) * 24ull)))->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] with _Tp = std::vector, _Alloc = std::allocator >, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference = std::vector&, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long long unsigned int'

If I try to use another variable to access the vector, like `int t1 = datavector[i][0];`, I get an error

> error: cannot convert 'std::vector' to 'int' in initialization

I thought a void pointer could be used to pass anything, so long as the proper cast was made. What is going on here?

Comment: The only thing valid to pass into the `void*` here is a `std::vector<std::vector<int> >*`. Don't use `void*` when you can use templates!

Comment: Its a *pointer* to a vector of vectors. You need to dereference the pointer before you start drilling into the `operator[]`. I.e. `(*datavector)[i][0]`

Comment: Also note that `sizeof(a)` is equivalent to `sizeof(int*)`.   I suspect this isn't what you intended to do here.

Comment: Can this be considered a typo question?

Comment: @Pubby - I don't have a choice in the matter. The functions are defined as having void* and I can't change them.

Comment: @BenC - no, that's not what I was intending. I think I've got something else figured out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `datavector` variable is a *pointer* to a vector of vectors of `int`, so you should apply proper dereferencing:

```
sumweight += a[i] * (*datavector)[i][0];
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

sumvalue += a[i] * (*datavector)[i][1];
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Moreover, this:

```
for (unsigned i=0; i < sizeof(a); i++)
//                     ^^^^^^^^^
```

Will *not* count the number of elements in the array (which makes me think that the `k` argument, which you are not using, is meant to contain the length of that array).

Comment: Nevermind, I had the parentheses in the wrong place. That part works now, thanks. I'm not using k for the size of the array because it's specified as something else. How else can I do that loop then?

Comment: @iamthesgt: Either pass a further parameter that specifies the number of elements in the array, or use an `std::vector` instead of the array (then, you can query its size through the `size()` member function).

Comment: Actually, I figured out how to do it. k is only the size of the array *in certain circumstances*, but this particular function only runs *in those circumstances*. And I can find the size of the array by the size of `(*datavector)`. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

First, your loop is wrong:

```
for(unsigned i=0; i<sizeof(a); i++)
```

`sizeof(a)` will always be `sizeof(int*)` because you cannot pass arrays to functions, regardless of your signature.  The argument will be a pointer, so you'll never be accessing your vectors properly.

Your next problem is that you have a pointer to a vector (bad idea in general), but you are not dereferencing it properly  You need one dereference before indexing into the next vector (and then into the next vector...), i.e.,

```
sumweight += a[i] * (*datavector)[i][0];
```

Next, ask yourself; why are you dealing with pointers to vectors of pointers to vectors?  It's a very sloppy and error prone solution.

Comment: I don't like doing it this way, but the function declarations are already there, and this is the best way I saw to do it.

Comment: @iamthesgt: Yes, exactly.  Arrays cannot be passed to or returns from functions; they will always degrade into pointers to their first element.  If you want to pass an array then you'll have to pass the size as well.  Better yet; use `std::array` (and pass a reference to it) and stop using pointers to vectors (of pointers...).  It complicates things, better to just pass references to vectors or, if you have to pass a `void*` (do you?  This is typically a rare use case in C++, reserved for things like C style callbacks.  Are templates an option?) then pass an object which holds a vector

Comment: No, this is for an assignment and I have to use the function declaration (which specifies `void*`). I'll look into changing it. Thanks for your help! I'd upvote if I could, but I don't have the rep